# count the number of vowels in a given string F#

Tags: string, count, functional-programming, f#

I need a method using List.fold that will count the number of vowels in a given string.
So far I have this method.

```
let vowels = ['a';'e';'i';'o';'u']
let isVowel =
    fun c -> vowels |> List.contains c

let count =
    String.filter isVowel
    >> String.length

printfn "%A" (count "aaaa")
```

It works fine, but I cannot figure out how to make a List.fold one using the same isVowel method. Here is my try.

The code below does not work, its purpose is to reflect my idea. Since the fold method applies the isVowel() which returns a true/false on each char in the string, if the condition is true it will add 1 to the accumulator which is the 0 parameter. When I try to use if else insinde the anon function I get an error.

```
let isVowel x = 
    match x with 
    | 'a' -> true
    | 'e' -> true
    | 'i' -> true
    | 'o' -> true
    | 'u' -> true
    | _ -> false

let countNumOfVowels =
    List.fold (fun (isVowel) (x) -> x + 1) 0 ["aaaa"]
```

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to use if/else inside the anonymous function?

Comment: let countNumOfVowels =
    List.fold (fun (isVowel) x -> if isVowel then x + 1 ) 0 [ "aaaa" ]

it does not make sense for me but at least I tried ))

Comment: the isVowel does not have the parameter, and the function does not have the char on which to call isVowel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fold a list but your source is actually a string.

A string can be interpreted as a sequence of chars if you use `Seq.fold`:

```
"abracadabra" |> Seq.fold (fun i c -> if isVowel c then i + 1 else i) 0

// val it : int = 5
```

Comment: can i convert the string into a sequence of chars and use it in the List.fold?

Comment: Of course, you can do a `List.ofSeq` and then a `List.fold`.

Comment: Note also you can use the same logic in your isVowels function and so simplify it. Make vowels a string too, hence: `let isVowels c = Seq.contains c "aeiou"`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for. Thanks Gus!

```
let countNumOfVowels str =
    List.fold (fun (x: int) (c: char) -> if (isVowel c) then x + 1 else x) 0 (Seq.toList str)

countNumOfVowels "Hello"
```

```
> countNumOfVowels "Hello";;
val it : int = 2
```